# In magento how to change the Manufacturer attribute input type from dropdown to multiselect from admin

Tags: magento

I need to edit the manufacturer input type from dropdown to multiselect.How to do update this from admin?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the attribute directly in the database. The table is `eav_attribute`. Look all the attributes and decide how to edit it. But simply what I think is changing:

```
frontend_input: select -> multiselect
backend_type: int -> text

*and maybe* 

backend_model: NULL -> catalog/category_attribute_backend_sortby
```

**NB.** I Didn't tried it. It's a good idea to get a backup before trying. And to try on a test installation first.