# How to change manfacturer dropdown to multi select in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need to edit the manufacturer input type from dropdown to multiselect.How to do update this from admin?

screenshot:
http://s33.postimg.org/zdhzam5wv/Capture.png

[image]

note:
this is duplicate question of [In magento how to change the Manufacturer attribute input type from dropdown to multiselect from admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227991/in-magento-how-to-change-the-manufacturer-attribute-input-type-from-dropdown-to) but i have no idea how to do it at magento 2.

Comment: there is no option in Magento2 to change attribute input type from  dropdown to multiple select ;

Comment: however you can delete and create new attribute with same attribute code from admin.
or If you want to change same attribute than you need to change it directly in Database as below : 
frontend_input = 'multipleselect' and backend_type = 'varchar'

Comment: I use your extension of "shop by brand" that do resync to manufacturer. I have a feeling if i change it on database -the extension will  fail

Comment: not sure about that , it may work with this updated db , you can give a try , but make sure to take backup of Database

Comment: Thanks! @EmizenTech

Comment: @EmizenTech, you may mark this as an answer. This is somehow dirty but it works :)

Answer (score 2):

there is no option in **Magento2** to change attribute input type from dropdown to multiple select

however you can delete and create new attribute with same attribute code from admin.

or If you want to change same attribute than you need to change it directly in Database as below

```
: frontend_input = 'multipleselect' and backend_type = 'varchar'
```

Comment: any possibility to update the answer with what table want to do this change?

Comment: hope this multipleselect should change as multiselect

Answer (score 2):

Yes, frontend_input should be 'mulitselect' and you need to update your frontend_model to 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend' and NULL out the source_model in the 'eav_attribute' table.

Comment: Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend This would be add in backend_model

Answer (score 2):

The other 2 answers are both incomplete. So here is a combination of both

Replace **`YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_ID_INTEGER`** with your *`attribute_id`* like **`355`**

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `backend_model`="Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Backend\\ArrayBackend",`backend_type`="varchar",`frontend_input`="multiselect", `source_model`=NULL WHERE `attribute_id`=YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_ID_INTEGER LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It still shows as a dropdown in the product page (admin)